# How to reverse order to pop out Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

Instead of it deleting the 'ALL' first, I would like the popitem to delete the 'CS' first and continue in that order from top to bottom.

Here is my code:

```
my_dictionary ={
's02.001':'CS',
's02.002':'OEM',
's02.003':'ALL'
}
numero = len(my_dictionary)
print(my_dictionary)
my_dictionary.popitem()
print(my_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's generally not a good pattern to use a dictionary as an ordered data type, you can do what you want like this:

```
my_dictionary.pop(next(iter(my_dictionary.keys())))
```

`.popitem()` doesn't take parameters, but `.pop()` does take a specific key to pop.

Comment: This wouldn't work - `keys` is not an iterable, it's a function.

Comment: Thanks, fixed @AKX and user2357112supportsMonica

Answer (score 0):

Even if dicts happen to be ordered in CPython 3.6+, they're the not right data structure if you need this sort of thing. I'd recommend using a list of 2-tuples instead.

If you don't want to do that, you can, as a hack, find the "first" key, then pop the value:

```
next_key = next(iter(my_dictionary))
next_value = my_dictionary.pop(next_key)
```

This may fail on other Python implementations than CPython.

Comment: A list isn't the right data structure either - popping from the start of a list is slow. A deque would be better.

Comment: Fixed, @Grismar.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Sure, though I'm also not sure OP actually needs to actually pop items either :)

Comment: Yeah, there's a pretty good chance that all they really need to do is for-loop over the dict. Still, if they do need to pop, then a list is inefficient. Using `next(iter(...))` this way is also inefficient - the more elements you pop, the more dummies end up cluttering the start of the dict's value array, and `next(iter(...))` has to go through all those dummies to find the first populated entry. A complete destructive iteration over a dict this way takes runtime quadratic in the dict's original size.

Answer (score 0):

Popitem removes an arbitrary key-value pair from the dictionary in Python versions older than 3.7. In 3.7+ popitem removes the last inserted key-value pair from the dictionary..

If you know the key, you can just remove the k, v pair from the dict. If you need the dict to stay in order, you can use an ordered dict. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

However it's worth noting that built-in dicts remember insertion order, which is guaranteed in Python 3.7+.

```
my_dictionary ={
's02.001':'CS',
's02.002':'OEM',
's02.003':'ALL'
}
numero = len(my_dictionary)
print(my_dictionary)

{'s02.001': 'CS', 's02.002': 'OEM', 's02.003': 'ALL'}

del my_dictionary['s02.001']
print(my_dictionary)

{'s02.002': 'OEM', 's02.003': 'ALL'}
```